# How to use eclipse to build PingFederate plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pingfederate

I have been writing some plugins for PingFederate using their SDK and build files. The process so far has been to use an editor (Atom) to write Java and an integrated cmd to run the ant build targets. The complexity of these plugins is growing and it is getting very weary todo it this way. As the plugin src directory contains the ant build files can I import it as a project and get the benefit of the Eclipse environment whilst writing the code.

I would like create a new workspace for PingFederate dev (Is this too catious) and use the ant tools to run the build targets. I have PingFederate installed locally so I should be able to resolve all required dependencies. Can anyone point me at a decent explanation of how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I have figured this out now and these are the steps I have followed:

Create a new workspace pointing at the PF/sdk directory (I wanted a separate workspace)

Create a project

- select configure default in the "Project Layout" section
- change src folder to java and output to build
- click next and then select the Libraries tab
- Click Add External Jars
- Browse for and add the pf-protocalengine.jar file
  (server/default/lib)

Build.xml

- Click Run - External Tools - External Tools Configuration Click Ant Build
- Select new from top left of screen to create one
- On main tab enter a name for the tool
- Use the browse file system button to search and find the build.xml file
- Select the targets tab and select the targets you are interested in

I intend to alter this tool for just compile or just deploy depending on where I am within the development of a plugin.